# D3 graph not updating range and domain on zoom for dynamic data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, d3.js

Graph works fine for first set of data. Plotting and zooming is good.
When we change the data set, the graph will be re-plotted correctly. But on zooming, the scales still remain the same(so high), that the plotted line will turn out to be really small.

I guess it's the problem with setting the domain and range.

Also the init graph method is called only once - which is responsible for the domain and range update.

Below is my code,

```
App.ReportsGraphView = Ember.View.extend( {

  //... global Variables...

  didInsertElement: function () {
    this.initGraph();
  },

  initGraph: function () {
    var self = this,
      title = this.get( 'title' ),
      element = this.$().get( 0 ),
      graph = {
        margin: {
          top: 40,
          right: 80,
          bottom: 50,
          left: 50
        },

    bisectDate: d3.bisector( function ( d ) {
      return d[ self.get( 'xField' ) ];
    } ).left
  };

    graph.width = this.$().width() - graph.margin.left - graph.margin.right;
    graph.height = 400 - graph.margin.top - graph.margin.bottom;

    graph.x = d3.time.scale()
      .domain(d3.extent(self.get( 'dataSource' ), function(d) { return d[ self.get( 'xField' ) ]; }))
      .range( [0, graph.width] );


    graph.y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(d3.extent(self.get( 'dataSource' ), function(d) { return d[ self.get( 'yField' ) ]; }))
      .range( [graph.height, 0] );

   graph.xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale( graph.x )
    .tickSize(-graph.height, 0)
    .tickPadding(10)    
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient( 'bottom' );

  graph.yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale( graph.y )
    .ticks( 4 )
    .tickSize( -graph.width )
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient( 'left' );

  graph.line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x( function ( d ) {
      return graph.x( d[ self.get( 'xField' ) ] );
    } )
    .y( function ( d ) {
      return graph.y( d[ self.get( 'yField' ) ] );
    } );

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(graph.x)
    .y(graph.y)
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var self = this;


    function zoomed() {
        //debugger;
        graph.node.select("g.x.axis").transition().call(graph.xAxis);
        graph.node.select("g.y.axis").transition().call(graph.yAxis);
        graph.node.select('path.line')
                .attr("d", graph.line(self.get( 'dataSource' )))
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
    }

graph.node = d3.select( element ).append( 'svg' )
  .attr( 'width', graph.width + graph.margin.left + graph.margin.right )
  .attr( 'height', graph.height + graph.margin.top + graph.margin.bottom )
  .append( 'g' )
  .attr( 'transform', 'translate(' + graph.margin.left + ',' + graph.margin.top + ')' )
  .classed( 'empty', true )
  .call(zoom);


graph.node.append( 'g' )
  .attr( 'class', 'x axis' )
  .attr( 'transform', 'translate(0,' + graph.height + ')' )
  .call( graph.xAxis );

graph.node.append( 'g' )
  .attr( 'class', 'y axis' )
  .call( graph.yAxis );

graph.title = graph.node.append( 'text' )
  .attr( 'class', 'graph-title' )
  .attr( 'x', graph.width / 2 )
  .attr( 'y', graph.height + 40 )
  .style( 'text-anchor', 'middle' )
  .text( title );

graph.focus = graph.node.append( 'g' )
  .attr( 'class', 'focus' )
  .style( 'display', 'none' );


graph.overlay = graph.node.append( "rect" )
  .attr( 'class', 'overlay' )
  .attr( 'width', graph.width )
  .attr( 'height', graph.height )
  .style( 'display', 'none' )
  .on( 'mouseover', function () {
    graph.focus.style( 'display', null );
  } )
  .on( 'mouseout', function () {
    var node = graph.overlay.node(),
      pos = d3.mouse( node ),
      nodeSize = node.getBBox();
    if ( pos[0] < 0 || pos[0] > nodeSize.width || pos[1] < 0 || pos[1] > nodeSize.height ) {
      graph.focus.style( 'display', 'none' );          
    }
  } )
  .on( 'mousemove', function () {

        var x0 = graph.x.invert( d3.mouse( this )[ 0 ] ),
          i = graph.bisectDate( graph.data, x0, 1 ),
          d0 = graph.data[ i - 1 ],
          d1 = graph.data[ i ],
          xField = self.get( 'xField' ),
          yField = self.get( 'yField' );

          if(d0 && d1){
          var d = x0 - d0[ xField ] > d1[ xField ] - x0 ? d1 : d0;

            graph.focus.attr( 'transform', 'translate(' + graph.x( d[ xField ] ) + ',' + graph.y( d[ yField ] ) + ')' );
          }  
  } );

this.set( '_graph', graph );
this.drawGraph( this.get( 'dataSource' ) );


},


drawGraph: function ( data ) {
    var graph = this.get( '_graph' ),
      xField = this.get( 'xField' ),
      yField = this.get( 'yField' ),
      title = this.get( 'title' );

if ( !this.get( 'canDrawGraph' ) ) {
  graph.node
    .classed( 'empty', true )
    .select( '.line' )
    .remove();

  graph.overlay.style( 'display', 'none' );

  this.drawEmptyAxes();
}
else {
  graph.node.classed( 'empty', false );

  if (this.get( 'from' ) && this.get( 'to' )) {
    graph.x.domain([this.get( 'from' ), this.get( 'to' )]);
  }
  else {
    graph.x.domain( d3.extent( data, function ( d ) {
      return d[ xField ];
    } ) );
  }
  graph.y.domain( [ 0, d3.max( data, function ( d ) {
    return d[ yField ];
  } ) ] );

  graph.node.select( '.x.axis' )
    .call( graph.xAxis );

  graph.node.select( '.y.axis' )
    .call( graph.yAxis );

  var line = graph.node.select( '.line' );

  if ( line.empty() ) {
    line = graph.node.append( 'path' )
      .attr( 'class', 'line' )
      .attr( 'color', '#000' );
  }

  line.attr( 'd', graph.line( data ) );

  graph.overlay.style( 'display', null );
}

graph.data = data;



  this.set( '_graph', graph );
  },

  drawEmptyAxes: function() {
    var graph = this.get( '_graph' );

graph.x.domain( [ moment().toDate(), moment().subtract( 'days', 1 ).toDate() ] );
graph.y.domain( [0, 1] );

graph.node.select( '.x.axis' )
  .call( graph.xAxis );

graph.node.select( '.y.axis' )
  .call( graph.yAxis );

this.set( '_graph', graph );


},

  canDrawGraph: function () {
    return !Ember.isEmpty( this.get( 'dataSource' ) ) && !Ember.isEmpty( this.get( 'xField' ) ) && !Ember.isEmpty( this.get( 'yField' ) );
  }.property( 'xField', 'yField', 'dataSource' ),

  didDataSourceChanged: function () {
this.drawGraph( this.get( 'dataSource' ) );


}.observes( 'dataSource' ),

  didAxesChanged: function () {
    this.drawGraph( this.get( 'dataSource' ) );
  }.observes( 'xField', 'yField' ),

  didTitleChanged: function () {

    var graph = this.get( '_graph' );
    var title = this.get( 'title' );
    var yField = this.get( 'yField' );
    var xField = this.get( 'xField' );

    graph.title.text( title );
  }.observes( 'title' ),

  actions: {
    onChoice: function ( checked ) {
      this.toggleProperty( 'isHidden' );
    }
  }

} );
```